# Kali Linux not appearing in grub after installation

Tags: linux, boot, system-installation, dual-boot, kali-linux

Today I installed Kali Linux via bootable USB, and during installation there was a problem installing the bootloader. So I skipped its installation and restarted my computer. But GRUB couldn't find the Kali Linux installed on my logical partition `sda4`, i.e., it didn't show the option to boot to Kali Linux.

Moreover, during my installation, I set the bootable flag as "no", and I don't know whether it will have any effect on the boot.

I have presently three operating systems installed on other partitions (Windows 7, Linux Mint 17, and Linux Mint 17.2) and today Kali. 
Installation was also completed.

So how do I boot to Kali Linux now??

This is the result after I tried the command `sudo update-grub`:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.18.2-031802-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.18.2-031802-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
 No volume groups found
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Linux Mint 17 Qiana (17) on /dev/sda7
done
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo update-grub` from one of your Linux-Mint systems?

Comment: no but going to do that now @Qeole

Comment: @Qeole I have edited the question